# Button ActionEvent send Email and show loading screen simultaneously

Tags: java, jframe

Currently I'm writing a little tool with java. The problem I have is the following:
When I press a button there should be two things starting simultaneously.

1. Start a IconImage (gif) loading image
2. Send an email with attachment (used this [code](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_send_email_with_attachment.htm))

I currently have the following code, which sends the email perfectly but there is no image visible. I also tried to start a new Thread but got lots of exceptions from the SendEmail class. Any suggestions?

```
        btnWeiter4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            URL loader = KeyLogger.class.getResource("/ajax-loader.gif");
            JLabel loading = new JLabel("loading ...\r\n");
            loading.setIcon(new ImageIcon(loader));
            loading.setVisible(true); // show loading image
            loading.setBounds(1087, 599, 121, 45);
            panel_4.add(loading);               

            SendEmail email = new SendEmail();
            email.send();   // sends email
          }
      });
```

**Update:**

It seems that there is an order. First the email is sent and after that my loading image is shown even if I `setVisible(true)` at the very beginning.

**Solution:**

I used anonymous inner class to create new Thread to send email and I moved the `file.delete();` inside `SendEmail` class. Works fine for me

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        SendEmail email = new SendEmail();
        email.send();   // sends email
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the setIcon method expects a String and not an URL, try it like this.

**Update** Now you can see when exactly which part of the code is executed

```
    btnWeiter4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
              @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


                JLabel loading = new JLabel("loading ...\r\n");
                loading.setBounds(1087, 599, 121, 45);
                loading.setIcon(new ImageIcon("ajax-loader.gif")); // Check whether the gif file is really in the root folder 
                loading.setVisible(true); // show loading image
        String currentTime    = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println("Im done with JPanel " + currentTime);
                panel_4.add(loading);               

                SendEmail email = new SendEmail();
                email.send();   // sends email
    String currentTime2    = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println("Im done with Email sending " + currentTime2);

              }
          });
```

Comment: I don't think the email is sent before showing the Jlabel, the ActionEvent code will be executed from top to buttom, how do you measure the time of Email sending?

Comment: Because the button is frozen for a short period of time 1-2 seconds and after that the image is visible

Comment: but this obviously does not solve my problem I just said your first comment under your answere is correct.